# Firebreath issue with cMake

Tags: plugins, browser, cmake, firebreath

I am at the stage of creating a VSS project for my First test plugin with Firebreath but I am running in to the following issue:

```
C:\code\sc>firebreath\prep2012.cmd projects build
A subdirectory or file build already exists.
Using projects in: "C:\code\sc\projects"
Generating build files in: "C:\code\sc\build"
NOTE: The build files in "C:\code\sc\build" should *NEVER* be modified directly.

When needed, make project changes in cmake files and re-run this script.
  Project-specific cmake files are found in [plugin dir]\CMakeLists.txt and
  [plugin dir]\Win\projectDef.cmake.
Note that parameters for cmake should be enclosed in double quotes, e.g. "-DVERB
OSE=1"
CMAKE parameters:

C:\code\sc\build>cmake -G "Visual Studio 11" -DFB_PROJECTS_DIR="C:\code\sc\proje
cts"  "C:\code\sc\firebreath"
'cmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: It looks like you have not installed CMake or CMake is not in your path. http://cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is because you either didn't install cmake or didn't add cmake to your path.

if you did install cmake, reinstall it and choose "add to path for all users" during the installation.  If you didn't, you need to install it.

all of this information is on the website: http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Building+on+Windows